# jQuery dialog box and fancy box conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox in the same page where i have used jquery dialog box

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $(".fancybox").fancybox(
            $("#ProductQuickView").css("display","")
        );
        $("#fbClose").click(function () { $.fancybox.close(); });

    });
```

but i am unable to use dialog box

```
  <script src="../Javascript/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../Javascript/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see a dialog anywhere in the code provided.

Comment: Sir, I have used a simple jquery dialog box

Comment: So where is the code which initializes it?

Comment: w8 den let me edit it..

Comment: $.dialog({   Content to display in dialog box  }); just below the document.ready

Comment: The dialog doesn't come from jquery but from jQuery UI and it needs to be initialized on an element. Also inside the options object goes the set of initialization options rather than content to display in the dialog.

Comment: thanku very much Sir.After discussing only I got the solution the solution

Comment: That I need to add Jquery.UI script in the page and that also on the top of all scripts and jquery fancy box script on the bottom of all the scripts